# Python:How to check if a list is a sublist of another list with duplicate values

Tags: python

Example:

```
lista = ['p','o','o','p']
listb = ['p','o','o','h','a','b','c']
```

if I use the issubset method, it will turn out to be True. When in fact lista is not a subset of listb. 
I'm coding in python by the way. 
To clarify, the code has to work in this case:

```
lista = ['p','o','o','p']
listb = ['p','o','o','h','p','b','c']
```

The above shall return true.

But,

```
lista = ['p','o','o','p']
listb = ['p','o','h','p','b','c']
```

The above will be false.
The first example is also false.

Comment: what is your definition of a sublist? should the order be considered or only the value counts?

Comment: order is not considered. just the value and the quantity of it. for example 'poop' as the sublist, it has two Ps and two Os, then the mainlist should have two Ps and two Os as well for the result to return True.

Answer (score 2):

You can join the lists to strings and check if one is part of the other:

```
lista = ['p','o','o','p']
listb = ['p','o','o','h','a','b','c']
''.join(lista) in ''.join(listb)
False


lista = ['p','o','o','p']
listb = ['p','o','o','p','h','a','b','c']
''.join(lista) in ''.join(listb)
True
```

Comment: I've never thought about comparing lists as strings. Nice! :)

Comment: this would fail if listb were ['p','o','o','h','p']

Comment: @GauravAgarwal since the auther never stated what his definition of a sublist is, it is not clear if this is an issue

Comment: @GauravAgarwal yeah this would be a problem.

Comment: This would fail if strings are longer than 1, this is not a solution

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can do it in less than O(N), by direct comparison.

This is an option:

```
def issublist(list_a, list_b):
    for i in range(len(list_b)-len(list_a)):
        if list_a == list_b[i:len(list_a)+i]:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: If one repeats different sublist searches, then it could be done faster by first indexing listb.

Answer (score 1):

Oneliner:

```py
any([lista==listb[i:i+len(lista)] for i in range(len(listb)-len(lista)+1)])
```

Comment: when i have this test case: lista = ['p','o','o','p']
listb = ['p','o','o','h','p','b','c'], it just doesn't work.

Comment: For that input it returns `False`. If you change `lista = ['p','o','o','h']` then it returns `True` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def removeElements(a, b): 
    n = len(a) 
    return any(a == b[i:i + n] for i in range(len(b)- n + 1)) 

print(removeElements(a, b))
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. It works now. You need to convert your list to set first.

Comment: Ok, this edit should work. It returns false in your case, as it should be. And it returns true if I write 'h' in place of the second 'p'. Is it ok now?